# Sencha CMD Linux command not found

Tags: installation, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, ubuntu-15.10

I'm trying to install Sencha-Cmd-6.0.2.14 in xUbuntu.

I downloaded `SenchaCmd-6.0.2-linux-amd64.sh.zip` and unzipped it to my desktop.

I installed Java by executing `sudo apt-get install default-jdk -y`.

Then I executed `./SenchaCmd-6.0.2.14-linux-amd64.sh`. The installation window appeared and I successfully went through the process.

Upon completion, I typed in `sencha` at the command prompt but I got a **command not found** error.

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal?

Comment: @jsve: yes, the terminal and the entire virtualbox have been restarted

Comment: Posting this on an old question, since it's meta feedback, and since you're a high-rep user who might want to know. There's no need to add "please help me", "I need help", "help appreciated" etc to your questions - it is fluff that may get removed in a future edit. Since readers know you need help, it may be read as a form of begging, and we get a _lot_ of that on Stack Overflow already. Please keep it succinct if you can - editors will appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sencha is probably not in your $PATH, I'm not sure where it installs but probably somewhere in your home directory. Make sure the Sencha install directory is not in your $PATH by issueing the following command in your terminal

```
echo $PATH
```

Assuming you use bash and sencha is now your $PATH, add, for example, this to your ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/sencha/cmd/6.0.2.14/bin
```

You need to find the correct path yourlself. That should do the trick.