# Sencha command not found in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

First I downloaded sencha CMD and changed the mode

```
sudo chmod +x SenchaCmd-6.5.1.240-linux-amd64.sh
```

Then I ran the installer

```
sudo ./SenchaCmd-6.5.1.240-linux-amd64.sh
```

I installed sencha CMD to the "/opt/" location and also I added path variable like.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.1.240/bin
```

and also

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.1.240/bin
```

But when I type sencha in my terminal it shows me 
"sencha: command not found"

Even I exported both path to $HOME/.bashrc file but nothing worked. So what can I do?
One thing, If I go to this /opt/Sencha/Cmd/ directory location and run this command

```
sudo ./sencha
```

It works, that's mean sencha is run.But It dose not work outside from the directory.
Please help me.

I also visited:

[Sencha CMD Linux command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400680/sencha-cmd-linux-command-not-found)

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/intro_to_cmd.html#intro_to_cmd_-_command_not_found

Comment: can you try with this remove old version from "/opt/Sencha/Cmd"  or rename folder by manually. may be it will work .

Comment: Yes, I did many times even I installed as it's default location(/root/sencha/cmd/6.5.1.240) and checked the option to set $PATH value during installation, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

on my machine, there is no binary in the bin folder. it's buried deep in directories. try

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/Sencha/Cmd/6.5.1.240
```

without the bin and see if it works.  there should be a symlink to sencha in that folder.